# Bootstrap submit button won't work

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, post, flask

I have the below code where I'm trying to submit data from a form into my back-end. Whenever I press the button it doesn't do anything and it's supposed to route to the specified place. I have looked at several examples and still hasn't worked. Below is my form. Any suggestions?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
            <h1>Sign Up</h1>
            <form action ="/adduser" method="POST" id="adduser">
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputUsername"> Username </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="InputUsername" placeholder="Enter username">
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                    <small class="text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                  </fieldset>
                  <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                </fieldset>
                <button class="btn btn-default" form="signup" type="submit">Sign up</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </dv>
</div>
```

Here is my route

```
@app.route('/adduser', methods=["POST"])
def adduser():
    print(request.form, file=sys.stderr)
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    email = request.form['email']

    models.User.create_user(email, password, username)
    login_user(user)
    return redirect_url('index.html')
```

Comment: When you submit the form, what happens?

Comment: nothing. I press the button and nothing happens. I'm printing out the form values to the console after I press the button on the back-end but they don't print out, so I'm assuming it's because the route never happens

Answer (score 2):

Your button has a `form` attribute of `signup` but your form has an `id` of `adduser`, so the button does not belong to the form. Try changing these values to match.